# Contract created by another contract and exceptions

Tags: solidity, contract-development, contract-deployment, exceptions, constructor

I have two questions regarding contract creation and exceptions:

1. If contract `A` creates contract `B` and then `throw`s in the same function, is `B` also deleted?
2. If contract `A` creates contract `B`, and `B` `throw`s in its constructor, does the exception bubble up to `A`?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

### 1. Yes

`B` will not be created if the transaction containing the creation of `B` has an exception.  Example:

```
pragma solidity ^0.4.8;

contract A {
    B public b;
    function foo() {
        b = new B();
        throw;
    }

    function getXfromB() returns (uint) {
        return b.x();
    }
}

contract B {
    uint public x;

    function B() {
        x = 1;
    }
}
```

Using [browser-solidity to quickly test](https://ethereum.stackexchange.com/questions/2835/how-to-quickly-test-a-solidity-function), first comment out the `throw`.  Then "Create" `A`, click `foo`, then click `b` to see its address and click `getXfromB` to see that you get 1.  Uncomment the `throw` to see that `B` is not created: click `b` to see it's 0x0.

An exception in a call causes all changes (in that call) to be reverted, and there is nothing special about contract creation that would keep it from being reverted.  For more information, see [Does an entire transaction revert when throw occurs?](https://ethereum.stackexchange.com/questions/8634/does-an-entire-transaction-revert-when-throw-occurs)

### 2. Yes

[Solidity 0.4](https://github.com/ethereum/solidity/blob/develop/Changelog.md#040-2016-09-08) was fixed so that if `new B()` fails, `A` will get an exception.

> Failing contract creation through "new" throws

The same example in #1 can be leveraged for testing by moving the `throw` in `foo` to constructor `B()`.

Comment: In case 2. the exception when I run `foo` in browser-solidity is `out of gas`, why is that?

Comment: Because the EVM essentially only has 1 exception: Out of Gas http://ethereum.stackexchange.com/questions/2307/why-does-a-solidity-throw-consume-all-gas

Comment: @eth technically, Invalid JUMPDEST is also a separate exception, and that's how `throw` works

Comment: @TjadenHess Agree the Yellow Paper labels 4 exceptions: Out of Gas, stack underflow, invalid JUMP, and invalid opcode.  In the link, I try to communicate that the implementation of the latter three end up with the first (Out of Gas).

Comment: I think it's more accurate to say that any exception causes all gas to be used up and state to be reverted; there's nothing special about the OOG exception

Comment: I think there's a valid point made in http://ethereum.stackexchange.com/questions/694/what-does-a-bad-jumpdest-error-mean that a compiler like Solidity can prevent the other exceptions.

Answer (score 1):

> 1. If contract A creates contract B and then throws, is B also deleted?

A `throw` will only terminate it's function. It cannot delete it's contract or any child contracts. For example ([from the solidity docs](http://solidity.readthedocs.io/en/develop/solidity-by-example.html?highlight=throw)):

```
contract Ballot{

    function giveRightToVote(address voter) {
        if (msg.sender != chairperson || voters[voter].voted) {
            throw;
        }
        voters[voter].weight = 1;
    }
}
```

If the `giveRightToVote()` function is called *and* if `msg.sender != chairperson || voters[voter].voted`, then the `giveRightToVote()` function will completely stop running; nothing past the throw will be executed - in this case we see `voters[voter].weight = 1` will not be executed.

However! The `Ballot{}` contract as a whole is still available on the blockchain for anyone else to call. And in fact `giveRightToVote()` could even still be called again, along with any other available functions within the contract.

If `Ballot{}` (Contract A) *had* created any Contract B. A throw in `Ballot{}` would not affect any of it's child contracts (Contract B).

> 2. If contract A creates contract B, and B throws in its constructor, does the exception bubble up to A?

A constructor is a function, so the same is true here. If a constructor throws, the rest of the constructor function will not be executed. But again, even after the constructor is thrown, the contract will remain and any other function within contract B will be available for future calls. Contract A will not be affected.

Comment: The takeaway from this answer is that a contract that has **already been deployed** to the blockchain, cannot be deleted by exceptions.  EDIT: Thanks Tjaden for mentioning the corrections to this answer.

Comment: A `throw` is guaranteed to revert any modifications made to the blockchain, including any newly created contracts, to the state before the `call`. Thus, in situation 1, the contract creation would be reverted. In situation 2, solidity does detect the failure and then throws, essentially reverting back to situation 1.

Comment: The original question was edited since this answer was submitted. @TjadenHess is correct.